# Javascript: Change image on keydown along with play audio

Tags: javascript

I am making a soundboard page and I have it playing audio and changing the image when clicking on the image. However I am trying to change the image when pressing on the specific keyCodes as well.

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    document.getElementById('myTune10').play();
  }
});
```

Here is the css for the image change. I am trying to use the RightThereOhkaye.jpg image when the keyCode is clicked.

```
button:active, .buttontwo:active {
background:url(images/RightDereOhkaye.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: Why didn't you just search the internet on how to change a background image with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById(...).style.background = 'url(images/RightThereOhkaye.jpg) no-repeat';
```

replace ... with Id of element where you want to update image

Comment: Alex S I tried that but it didn't work. Here is how I updated my code:

if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    document.getElementById('myTune10').play();
    document.getElementById('myTune10').style.background = 'url("images/RightThereOhkaye.jpg") no-repeat';
  }

Comment: images/ is relative path to the url of current page. Try to use absolute url to the image, beginning with http://...

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**

1. `keydown` is only tracking the key itself, not the state of the key.
   So, if you press <kbd>a</kbd> key on your keyboard, `KeyDown`
   generates a KeyCode of Keys.A and if you press
   <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> you also get a KeyCode of Keys.A. So,
   to recognize the difference between the
   <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and the <kbd>a</kbd>, you have to use
   `keypress` instead of `keydown`.
2. In fact, You want to change the background image, when the audio is
   playing. So, there is no need to change it when a key is pressed.
   You can create a function for play audio on keypree and change the
   background when audio is playing.

See the code snippet below:

```js
var player = document.getElementById( 'myTune10' ),
    button = document.getElementById( 'button' );

/* Play / Pause when 'A' Key pressed */
document.addEventListener( 'keypress', function( e ) {
  var char = e.which || e.keyCode;

  if ( char == 65 ) button.click()
} )

/* Add click event to play button */
button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  ( player.paused ) ? player.play() : player.pause()
} )

/* Add class and change image when audio is playing */
player.addEventListener( 'play', function() {
  button.classList.add( 'pause' )
} )

/* Remove class and change image when audio paused */
player.addEventListener( 'pause', function() {
  button.classList.remove( 'pause' )
} )

/* Show contents when data for the current frame is available and loaded */
player.addEventListener( 'loadeddata', function() {
  document.getElementById( 'player' ).style.display = 'block'
} )
```

```css
#player {
  display: none
}
.play {
  width: 48px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #eee url(https://www.w3.org/TR/WWWicn/play-start.gif) center center no-repeat
}
.pause {
  background-image: url(https://www.w3.org/TR/WWWicn/play-pause.gif)
}
```

```html
<div id="player">
  <h2>Click here and press &ldquo;A&ldquo; (Capital letter) to Play / Pause.</h2>
  <button type="button" id="button" class="play"></button>
  <audio id="myTune10">
    <source src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/432/432256_4397472-lq.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>
</div>
```